# ntdll!RtlWaitOnAddress exception when gdb starts

Tags: c++, windows, debugging

When gdb starts in windows 10, error message is received.
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffe7c493466 in ntdll!RtlWaitOnAddress () from C:\windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/soAK0.png)

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Whatever "WwPsProtect64.dll` is is causing you issues. Sounds like some kind of anti-virus and/or something which injects dlls of some kind maybe? There's very little information on google on it. You should try to understand what software you've got installed which adds and/or injects this dll into your process.